# How to create Circular Reel view in Android?

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, ios-autolayout

[image]

How can I create view like this in Android? I have created that circular main frame image using drawable circle shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="#000"/> <!-- this one is ths color of the  Rounded Button -->
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:topRightRadius="100dp"/>
</shape>
```

How to place the inner images in this circular frame?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Use your Circular Reel image as a mask: cutout the picture slots so that the alpha is Zero where the pictures go.  You will draw this image last over the top of your pictures.

Each image in each slot will need to be rotated and translated into the slot positions.  Rotate the image first (about the center of the image) and then translate the image into it's slot.

You don't need to do this dynamically as the slots are all fixed.  This means you calculate the image transform using regular old pen and paper and then build each transform by hand into your layout markup.  Some useful formulas come from Polar coordinate systems (r, theta) and conversions to Cartesian (x,y).  All my math in the picture is in degrees, but you'd better work in radians.

`R` is the radius of the circle, the distance from the center of the reel to the center line of the view slots.

If I were you (and if you wanted to change the images dynamically) then I would find out how to specify an empty slot for each transform and add the images in ex post facto.

Practice getting a single image lined up, then work the math for the rest of the slots.

Comment: Thanks, @james I will try this and get back to you. Thanks a lot

Comment: can you please provide some code for help I didn't get it completely. Thanks